# All Windows files accessible from Kubuntu except for those in OneDrive folder

Tags: dual-boot, mount, kubuntu, windows, files

I'm dual booting Kubuntu 20.10 and Windows 10, and I have not mounted the NTFS Windows drive in Kubuntu. In the Dolphin file manager, it is shown as "Basic data partition". I can read and write files in most folders under `C:/Users/George` from both Windows and Kubuntu and have the changes show up in the opposite OS.

However, attempts to read or write to my OneDrive folder from Kubuntu both fail. When attempting to read, all files and folders appear with the correct name, but appear in Dolphin as 0 bytes. When opening a file, Dolphin throws an error `Unable to run the command specified. The file or folder /media/george/1E264B55264B2D59/Users/George/OneDrive/test.txt does not exist.` When copying a file into the folder, Dolphin does not show any error, but the file does not copy either.

I have made sure that all files in OneDrive are actually offline by opening them in Windows without the OneDrive app open.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: anything in [this reference](https://gist.github.com/starlinq/0f98c6d9339497bb8ac42d67f66f60eb) which helps?

Comment: The OneDrive (and similar file backup service) folders use some sort of placeholder files IIRC - they don't really exist but are fetched when required (maybe using some virtual filesystem, not sure). So you can't really access them from outside Windows

Comment: Does this help? https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/02/how-to-keep-onedrive-in-sync-with.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

This is because, in Windows, you have OneDrive configured to use files on-demand.

To replicate the same under Linux, to access your files under Linux, you need to utilise the following application: https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver

No other solution is possible, without you first disabling files on-demand under Windows.

Comment: Thank you. I made the mistake of thinking that available offline = files on-demand is disabled.

Comment: +1 as the onedrive client for linux is great. I've now moved to using OneDrive on windows, with all files downloaded, and accessing it "passively" in linux, in which case the solution at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/1728354 worked well for me on ubuntu 22.04, i.e. getting hold of onedrive.zip and unpacking the plugin to the appropriate location (via `sudo cp -pv Downloads/ntfs-plugin-9000001a.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ntfs-3g`)